# Grouping a LongListSelector containing ListBoxes inside ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Hello I am trying to databind ListBoxes residing inside ItemTemplate of LLS, so far I have seen grouping applied to a template containing only Textblocks, but I need the 'collection' being grouped by. I know my requirements are not that much *practical* but I am badly in need of it.

MY MODEL

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    private string _id;
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _lineOne;
    public string LineOne
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineOne;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lineOne)
            {
                _lineOne = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LineOne");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _lineTwo;
    public string LineTwo
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineTwo;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lineTwo)
            {
                _lineTwo = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LineTwo");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

MY VIEWMODELS

```
public class GroupedItemViewModel
{
    public string Key2
    {
        get
        {
            return _key2;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _key2)
            {
                _key2 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Key2");
            }
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _grp;
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> GroupedItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _grp;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _grp)
            {
                _grp= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("GroupedItems");
            }
        }

    }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<GroupedItemViewModel> GroupedPhotos
    {
        get
        {
            var finalQuery = Items
   .GroupBy(category => category.LineOne)
   .Select(grouping => new GroupedItemViewModel { Key2 = grouping.Key,    GroupedItems = grouping.ToObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>() });

            return new ObservableCollection<GroupedItemViewModel>(finalQuery);

        }
    }
```

}

MY VIEW - LLS

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
        <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedPhotos}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate3}" GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource header}"/>
</Grid>
```

MY VIEW - DATA TEMPLATE OF LLS

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate3">
        <Grid>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate4}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate2}"/>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

MY VIEW - DATA TEMPLATE OF LISTBOX

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate4">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}"/>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

MY VIEW - DATA TEMPLATE OF GROUP HEADER

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="header">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key2}"/>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```